# Forms WebBrowser control and css gradients in IE

Tags: jquery, wpf, browser, jscrollpane, gradient

I have a WPF Application using a windows forms WebBrowser control inside a WindowsFormsHost. The page in this control uses jquery and jscrollpane to create a customized scrollbar. With CSS, I'm setting the jspArrowDown background to a gradient. In XP (and only XP it seems) there is an issue displaying the gradient. This same gradient background is used in the jspArrowUp element with no problems. Even more odd is the fact that the IE proper on the same box displays the gradient background perfectly fine. Has anybody encountered this unique situation or one similar to it with the windows forms WebBrowser control? If so, how was it resolved?

**Identical CSS**

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#CCCCCC');
```

**Identical User Agent**

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
```

**Different Visual Results**

IE Proper

[image]

Windows Form WebControl

[image]

**Update**

After having this error crop up in a Windows 7 environment, I did some more digging and realized it really wasn't the fact that the environment is XP, it was the fact that the environment didn't have IE 9.0 installed. The WebBrowser control is running IE 7.0 regardless of what machine I run on, but if the machine has IE 9 installed, it will render using the Trident 5.0 engine instead of the Trident 4.0 engine that comes with IE 7 and IE 8. So the issue is actually happening with Trident 4.0. Is there any way to get Trident 5.0 on to an XP machine?

Comment: Which version of IE? Can you upgrade to IE 8 and check if same problem persists?

Answer (score 0):

Webbrowser is a wrapper around IE APIs. it's stuck to IE7 rendering engine.

You can try to use a better version. Rick will help you to do that : http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. If you notice the user agent string above, I was already incorporating this fix and running IE 8 (MSIE 8.0;) in the browser control

Comment: and did you try IE 9? Sorry.. I don't see anything else to help you. Normally, it should be the same sdk behind the browser and webbrowser except some settings. The devil may be in the details... and the settings.

Comment: well, the issue only happens in XP, which doesn't support ie9